# Can the players see the enemy in CounterStrike?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive, counter-strike

I was watching a Counter Strike match today and noticed that the enemy figures were outlined in the view. Can the player see this, or is it just for the benefit of spectators?

If the player can see it, what is the logic of allowing the players to see each other through walls?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The counterstrike [wiki](http://counterstrike.wikia.com/wiki/GOTV#GOTV) states the following in regards to spectating:

> In Counter-Strike: Global Offensive, non-dead player spectators are
>   allowed to use the X-ray by pressing a key (default X). When turned
>   on, the team-colored silhouette of all players is shown through the
>   walls. For instance, a blue aura will display a CT player. Grenade
>   trails are also shown in their respective hues.
>
> In casual matches, dead players are allowed to spectate both their
>   teammates and their enemies, as well as view in either first person,
>   chase cam or free cam. Team chat (both text and voice) is disabled
>   when the player spectates in this mode.
>
> In competitive matches, dead players can only watch their teammates in
>   first person. However, unlike in casual mode, players can chat or use
>   their microphones to communicate regardless of their current status.
>   The HUD for non-dead player spectators in Competitive matches also
>   show the equipped weapon and equipments, health and armor for all 10
>   players.
>
> In bomb defusal games (regardless of casual or competitive) if the C4
>   has been planted and the entire Terrorist team is dead, the spectator
>   view for dead Terrorist players will focus only on the C4. Also, when
>   spectating a competitive game, the C4 is outlined in yellow when
>   dropped, red if planted and green when defused.
>
> In game modes that do not allow players to respawn, bots can be
>   controlled by their respective team members who were killed in the
>   same round. This has garnered some controversy, especially in casual
>   mode, as spectating players can see the enemy's position, take control
>   of a bot, and quickly eliminate opponents.

**Recap**
In casual play the text and voice chat are disabled to prevent cheating.
In competitive matches players can only see their teammates.

Comment: I know you can't see the outlines in competitive or casual matchmaking (I don't think?), can you see them for teammates in other game types?

Answer (score 5):

**No**. Players in a competitive setting cannot see the outline of other players, teammates or otherwise. Allowing other players to see this would be literally giving all players a wallhack.

Other similar spectator vision assistance, like replacing flashbang screen whiteout with text that says "Blinded" is also not enabled for anyone but spectators.

Answer (score -1):

Normal online games no you can’t see the outline but yes in the tournaments you see on tv all teams are aloud to see the outlines.  Not sure why they do this but I’ve been to a few events and talked to the players and they all say they can see the outlines of the opposite team.